# using Atom.io with winscp

Tags: winscp, atom-editor

I am not able to configure winscp to work with ATOM.IO/

I tried to add external editor from the wincsp settings however when I clicked on the file to edit, an command line is opening and nothing happen.

external url : C:\Users\yjradeh\AppData\Local\atom\Update.exe !.!

any help on this ?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: I re-posted an equivalent question on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/930136/how-to-set-up-atom-io-as-a-winscp-external-editor)

Answer (score 19):

I guess the question is off topic, but since it's here and I was JUST trying to figure this out, I thought I would leave an answer just in case.

You need to find the location of the atom.io executable, `atom.exe`. The update is just run to check for updates and then starts the executable with some other commands. I don't think you can use the `Update.exe` to start the editor at a specific file, at least not through winscp.

For me, I found that the atom.exe was installed to

`C:\Users\mynamehere\AppData\Local\atom\app-0.187.0\atom.exe`

So I just copied and pasted this into my winscp editor preferences and it seemed to work fine.

Sidenote: I'm also going to be trying out some of the sftp plugins for atom as they might be better than using winscp if they allow the use of authorization keys. There seem to be plenty of choices.

Update (3/22/16): I found that atom installs itself in the PATH. So now I just add atom as an external editor and use the command

`atom !.!`

Comment: Using just `atom` was a lifesaver. Thanks!